# MarkerWithLabel always prints black text rather than colour specfied

Tags: javascript, google-maps

I am using MarkerWithLabel.js V1.1.9 the problem I am having is when I goto print the marker text always shows up black rather than white which is the colour I specified. I am overlaying white text on a red marker which looks fine on screen but when printed or print previewed the text is always printed in black. I am using the below for the label class

```
.labels {
        color: white;
        font-family: "Lucida Grande", "Arial", sans-serif;
        font-weight: boldfont-weight: bold;
        font-size: 9px;
        text-align: center;
        width: 18px;
        white-space: nowrap;
        }
```

is there anything I should add to make sure it prints the text in white?

Answer (score 0):

You can try adding background-color:"" property and see if that solves the issue.

You do not have any background color specified which does not affect in the UI because 'labelInBackground' boolean is set to false by default which makes the label appear in foreground and you can see it.

Also, another problem would be that printers usually can not print white unless you have special white ink cartridge. Check your printer specs and cartridge. I'm quite sure its because of printer issue. There are workarounds for the same, you can search for those in the web.

Comment: Tried as suggested but sadly it makes no difference.

Comment: Well mostly its a printer problem then. Get a white Ink, replace the black cartridge with the white one and see if it prints.